# make vb.net date format consistent with sql server

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my sql server, my date is stored as "Jul 5 2005 12:00AM"
I'm using vb.net to pull date from sql. I wonder how I can make the format in vb.net consistent with that in sql?

I tried something like

```
 textbox1.text= Format(variable, "mmm dd yyyy HH12:MI"),
```

but doesn't work well.

Thanks for advice!

Comment: You're storing the date as text in Sql Server? When you say it doesn't work well, exactly how does it not work well?

Comment: yes, i'm using varchar(50), and when i insert a timestamp, i uses NOW in vb.net as a date format

Comment: Is there a reason you can't store the date as a `datetime` in Sql Server? That might make everything a lot easier.

Comment: Why are you using `Format`?  That's a legacy VB function - I would suggest looking at the formatting options available in the .NET framework.

Comment: i used to store as datetime, then i realizes that if i store as varchar(50), it's more readable in sql server

Comment: Go back to using `datetime`, or your project will end in tears.

Comment: thanks, I will have a try

Comment: _it's more readable_ ? Does your user use Sql Server Management Studio to read the date? The _display format_ used to show the date to you or to your user has nothing to do with the value of a datetime. Store always the value not its string representation. You have plenty of functionality to show your date back to your user

Comment: If you store as a string, you lose a lot of functionality... How would you find all records that relate to Wenesdays, or all records between two dates? You can't even sort chronologically (unless you pick a date format like YYYYMMDD which defeats your "readable" purpose anyway)

Answer (score 0):

You should not store dates as strings. There are built-in data types for dates. You materialise the date as a string in your program with something like

```
TextBox1.Text = variable.ToString("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm tt")
```

where `variable` is a DateTime.

See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for what you can use in the format string.

Comment: i get an error says:Input string was not in a correct format?

Comment: i've rebuilt the table and store the date as datetime format, then in vb.net set, i dim the variable as datetime

Comment: @user3344443 I suggest you use [Option Strict On](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) and correct whatever it finds wrong. I tested that statement and it worked (`Dim dt As Date = New DateTime(2014, 5, 24, 21, 30, 0) : Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("MMM dd yyyy hh:mm tt"))`).

Comment: @user3344443  I think you missed the part about `where variable is a DateTime`

Comment: thanks for your advice, I'm new to vb.net, not sure about option strict on, but I tried Format(variable, "MMM dd yyyy h:mm:ss tt"), it works ok now

Comment: @user3344443 Option Strict is in project settings, under Compile. Turning it on means that you have to code using types properly. It makes code ~30% faster and means you'll find a lot more of your bugs at compile time (in Visual Studio) than at run time (when running the app). You can set it to be on by default in VS options. There is no good reason to have it off except for legacy apps (and even they should be updated). It will also make you code better. Eg this `Dim A As String = 1` will no longer work (`1` isn't a String).